# Flutter MVC: Where to put requests

Tags: flutter

I would like to apply a MVC pattern to my flutter project.

Model - some classes which contain data
View - everything with UI
Controller - some logic components like incrementing a value or something

Where would I store requests to the backend like the following?:

```
Future<String> attemptLogIn(String username, String password) async {
    var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(SERVER_IP + '/login'),
        body: {"username": username, "password": password});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) return res.body;
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: return AttemptLoginModel.fromJson(); which is located in your Model

Comment: do you want to know where to store data retrieved by the Future or where to put API calls?

Comment: @CarlosSandoval I just want to know where I store the requests functions in general. Where should I put the API calls? Model, View or Controller?

Comment: In view, you will show your UI and in the init() function you will call the controller function

Comment: thanks, that should be the answer to my question